# ¿Cómo solucionar error de apache relacionado con el mod rewrite?

Tags: apache, url

Antes de todo quiero informar que estoy desarrollando una aplicación en local por preferencia utilizo **XAMPP**.

El problema es que no puedo crear url amigables para mis paginas 
tengo habilitado el modulo de `modwrite` pero sim embargo este no funciona
en mi archivo `.htaccess` situado en la carpeta de `htdocs` de **XAMPP** esta el código fuente para ocultar las extensiones de los archivos **php** y **html**, pero cuando trato de acceder a mi **localhost** este me da un error 500.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond % {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond % {REQUEST_FILENAME} \.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: En la tercera linea estas colocando una espacio inesario antes del slash invertido.

Comment: ...en la 3 antes de `\.html`. Y también en las 2 y 3 entre el `%` y `{`

Comment: utiliza esto para probar to configuración: http://htaccess.mwl.be/

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
AllowOverride All
```

Así de simple funciona!

Suerte!